# Ошибка 407 при использовании cookie и прокси-сервера

Tags: c#, .net

Приведенный ниже код работает через прокси-сервер, вытаскивая настройки прокси  из IE и credentials:

```
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.СЕКРЕТНЫЙ_САЙТ.ru");
myWebRequest.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Однако если я добавляю куки к такому запросу:

```
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.СЕКРЕТНЫЙ_САЙТ.ru");
myWebRequest.CookieContainer = cc;
myWebRequest.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

То сервер возвращает ошибку:

> Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (407) Требуется проверка
>   подлинности посредника.

Важный момент: прокси блокирует доступ к сайту, если писать без WWW.
Вероятно причина именно в этом. Однако в кукиконтейнере я пишу домен с www:

```
string cookie = "uid=566675; ..................";
cc = new CookieContainer();
cc.PerDomainCapacity = 100;
Uri target = new Uri("http://www.СЕКРЕТНЫЙ_САЙТ.ru/");
MatchCollection coll = new Regex(@"([^\s]+?)=([^;]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline).Matches(cookie);
if (coll.Count != 0) {
    foreach (Match m in coll) {
        string par = m.Groups[1].ToString();
        string value = m.Groups[2].ToString();
        cc.Add(new Cookie(par, value) { Domain = target.Host });
    }
}
else cc = null;
```

Как сделать, чтобы прокси пропускал запросы с cookie?

Comment: Гугл уже давно использует `HTTPS`

Comment: это я написал для примера, адрес сайта конечно совершенно другой, ну и я написал же,что в первом варианте кода - запросы ходят нормально через прокси

Comment: такие вещи нужно указывать в вопросе.

Comment: @z668, тем не менее первый вариант кода возвращает HTML код, значит запрос отрабатывает. Тут проблема совсем в другом

Comment: для тестирования задайте параметры авторизации напрямую: myWebRequest.Proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(@"userName", @"password ", "Domain");

Comment: @z668, пробовал, ситуация аналогичная. То есть если без куков, то запрос отрабатывает. Подцепляю куку - ошибка 407. Может как-то нужно по-особенному настрfивать заголовки headers?

Comment: не знаю что за вредный прокси-сервер такой, и узнать к сожаленью не могу..

Comment: попробуйте любое стороннее решение. Возьмите тот же бесплатный xNet (просто для теста) и проверьте на нем: http://habrahabr.ru/post/146475/

Comment: @z668, мне, кстати, тоже очень не нравится, что от моего имени какой-то робот комментарии пишет. я его (комментарий) удалил. и этот комментарий тоже удалю через некоторое время, чтобы не загрязнять обсуждение.

Comment: @z668, в моем распоряжении NetFramework 2.0 , а xNet требует выше..

Comment: вопрос очень специфичный, запрашиваемый мной домен прокси блокирует, если его писать без www. Видимо это связанно именно с этим фактом. Хотя я в кукиконтейнере таргет указываю с WWW, прокси все равно не пропускает этот запрос на домен c WWW. Но например с  такой кукой прокси пропускает запрос на другие сайты, например Google.ru